# How can I see a translation in my website

Tags: python, html, css, django, translation

I am currently working on my website, which is a translator which you input a phrase and it gets translated into an invented language.

Here's the code of the translator function:

```
def translator(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "a":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "U"
            else:
                translation = translation + "u"
        elif letter.lower() in "t":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "A"
            else:
                translation = translation + "a"
        elif letter.lower() in "c":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        elif letter.lower() in "g":
            if letter.isupper:
                translation = translation + "C"
            else:
                translation = translation + "c"
    return translation
```

However, I am stuck in showing this funcion in my web, here's the code in views.py:

```
from .translate import translator

def translator_view(request):
    
    return render(request,'main/translator.html')

def translated_view(request):
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    print('text:', text)
    translate = translator
    dt = translator.detect(text)
    tr = translated.text
    context = {
        'translated': tr
    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```

Here's the template where you introduce the text:

```
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method= "get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>
    
    </div>   
</form>
```

Here's the template that should would show the translation.

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div>
    <center><h2 class="display-4">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY INTO</h2></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>
        {{ translated }}
    </h3>
</div>   

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: I have given you an answer. If it was helpful please trick. Thank You

Comment: I'm trying it right now, I've chosen get 'cause I really don't wanna store this in a database, like a generic translator. However, I am going to try it this way.

Comment: great, well using a post request doesn't mean you are putting it to a database it means you are not sending anything through the URL. Which means post method is safer than get when sending data.

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me that, I'm kind of a noob in coding

Comment: So did it work? So if I have helped you could you like please trick my answer. Thanks

Comment: No it hasn't, I'm still trying to figure out some syntax problems. However, the Post method solved some problems. So thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using GET request I think the best thing to do is to use a POST request.

```py
def translated_view(request):
    text = request.POST['text']
    print('text:', text)
    translate = translator
    dt = translator.detect(text)
    tr = translated.text
    context = {
        'translated': tr
    }
    return render(request, context, 'main/translated.html')
```

```
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>
    </div>   
</form>
```

But if you really want to use get request then you have an error. You haven't put a name attribute in the textarea so in your case it's:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
```

and it your view its:

```py
text = request.GET.get('text')
```